# Getting KeyError: in my Python script

Tags: json, python-2.7

I am trying to build script which will download images using Python. I am having a problem in the code as the keyerror in Python v 2.7.11 is occurring. My code is

```
import urllib, urllib2, demjson, os
json = demjson.JSON()
def read_newbooks_file(path):

data = open(path)
isbnlist = []
for isbn in data.readlines():
    isbnlist.append(isbn.replace("\n",""))
return isbnlist

isbns = read_newbooks_file("C:\\newbooks.txt")
print isbns
for isbn in isbns:
    url="http://openlibrary.org/api/search?q={%22query%22:%22(isbn_10:(" + isbn + ")%20OR%20%20isbn_13:(" + isbn + "))%22}"
    response=urllib.urlopen(url)
    book=json.decode(response.read())
    if book["result"]!=[]:
        results = book["result"]
        print results
        url = "http://openlibrary.org/api/get?key=" + results[0]
        OLResult=urllib.urlopen(url)
        data=demjson.decode(OLResult.read())
        print data
        imgurl = 'http://covers.openlibrary.org/b/olid/' + results[0][3:] + '-M.jpg'
        imgfile = urllib.urlretrieve(imgurl, "C:\\" + isbn + ".jpg")
        fsize = os.path.getsize(imgfile[0])
        if fsize < long(1000):
            os.remove("C:\\" + isbn + ".jpg")
        gparams = urllib.urlencode({'bibkeys': isbn, 'jscmd':'viewapi','callback':'gcallback'})
        opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPHandler())
        request = urllib2.Request('http://books.google.com/books?%s' % gparams)
        opener.addheaders = [('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.3) Gecko/2008092417 Firefox/3.0.3')]
        g = opener.open(request).read()
        print g
        if g != "gcallback({});":
            g = g[10:-2]
            gbookinfo=demjson.decode(g)
        if gbookinfo[isbn].has_key("info_url"):
            print "GB info url: " + gbookinfo[isbn]["info_url"]
        if gbookinfo[isbn].has_key("thumbnail_url"):
            print "GB thumbnail url: " + gbookinfo[isbn]["thumbnail_url"]
            opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPHandler())
            request = urllib2.Request(gbookinfo[isbn]["thumbnail_url"])
            opener.addheaders = [('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.3) Gecko/2008092417 Firefox/3.0.3')]
            picfile = open("C:\\" + isbn + "-g.jpg", "w+b")
            picfile.write(opener.open(request).read())
```

Error I am getting is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python25/first.py", line 16, in <module>
    if book["result"]!=[]:
KeyError: 'result'
```

Comment: There is no key named `result` in the book json. Just putup a print statement and check what keys the book have.

Comment: Please review the help files to see how to format code.

Comment: @DivakarDass after putting print statement i got output as {u'status': u'error'}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `book` is empty, or if the key you are trying to check for a value isn't there, you'll get a key error. 
 You can use `in` to check if a key exists within a `dict`
For example, if `book` is empty, or missing your key, you can use something like:

```
if 'result' in book:
    book['result'] = ..... # Do something
```

This way, you know that the key exists and that your `book['result ']` is a valid statement that won't raise a key error. Also, it will help you debug if for example your `book` dictionary  is empty or doesn't have your desired key.

Hope that helps

Comment: If your result is {u'status': u'error'} then your error is coming from reading the url - hence why no 'result' in your return dict. That's where you need to debug. Not on the keyError